# Desktop icon does not appear in LXQt

Tags: lubuntu, icons, gui, lxqt

I am using Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with LXQt 0.17.1 and am trying to launch the intel vtune-gui (standalone version installed from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/vtune-profiler-download.html?operatingsystem=linux&distributions=online) and environment variables set from instructions [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-vtune/top/linux-os.html)) via a desktop icon. While I can easily launch this from the command line with `vtune-gui`, I want to use a desktop icon (the location for which is `/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2023.0.0/bin64/vtune-gui.desktop`); however, when searching the applications menu by clicking the bird in bottom left corner and searching `vtune`, nothing appears. **How can I make sure the desktop icon appears in the application menu?**

Comment: https://lxqt-project.org/blog/2022/06/18/menu-editing-in-lxqt/   You mentioned your OS/release, but not which LXQt you're using (ie. the default, or you've added the later version available via *Lubuntu Backports*).  The Lubuntu Manual page for Desktop Icons can be [found here](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html) (*assuming default LXQt; the LTS manual link I provided may not be the best link if using the Backports LXQt which is the stable version*)

Comment: I was able to add the icon via the first link you sent. Thanks!

Comment: If you've got your answer; feel free to write your own answer (& gain the rep.).  Please use the link that was useful to you (*or both*), you can reference me (*or not, your choice*) as I don't have time to write up anything currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the instructions suggested by @guiverc from [here](https://lxqt-project.org/blog/2022/06/18/menu-editing-in-lxqt/), I did the following:

1. Opened PCManFM-Qt File Manager
2. Navigated to `~/.local/share/applications` using the file manager
3. Clicked `Tools > Create Launcher`
4. Added `/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2023.0.0/bin64/vtune-gui` and `/opt/intel/oneapi/vtune/2023.0.0/bin64/resources/app/icons/VTune.png` to the `Command` and `Icon` fields respectively in the `Create Launcher` interface.
5. In the desktop applications launcher, which can be accessed by clicking the bird in the bottom left corner, the desktop icon for Vtune (or whatever you name the launcher) appears in the `Other` menu (by default, right below the `Office` menu).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer :)